How to construct A HashMap in an inductive type?
As a completely new user of Lean 4, I am trying to build a TOML parser as an exercise. I tried defining the beginnings of a TOML value as an inductive type:
import Std.Data.HashMap

--
-- A definition of the kinds of types given in the TOML specification at
-- https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#objectives.
--
inductive TOMLType where
    | boolean (b : Bool)
    | integer (n : Int)
    | float (n : Float)
    | string (s : String)
    | array (elems : Array TOMLType)
    | table (kvPairs : HashMap String (fun _ => TOMLType))
    -- TODO: add more types like DateTime here.

However, this is giving me the following error:
✖ [3/10] Building SantunLeanTOMLParser.TOMLTypes
trace: .> LEAN_PATH=././.lake/build/lib DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= /usr/local/lean/v4.14.0/bin/lean ././././SantunLeanTOMLParser/TOMLTypes.lean -R ./././. -o ././.lake/build/lib/SantunLeanTOMLParser/TOMLTypes.olean -i ././.lake/build/lib/SantunLeanTOMLParser/TOMLTypes.ilean -c ././.lake/build/ir/SantunLeanTOMLParser/TOMLTypes.c --json
error: ././././SantunLeanTOMLParser/TOMLTypes.lean:13:21: function expected at
  HashMap
term has type
  ?m.21
error: Lean exited with code 1
Some required builds logged failures:
- SantunLeanTOMLParser.TOMLTypes
error: build failed

What am I doing wrong?

You may want to look at Lean’s JSON type and the note they have there about the kv pairs. https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/ffac974dba799956a97d63ffcb13a774f700149c/src/Lean/Data/Json/Basic.lean#L175-L185. (It also applies to HashMap since that is also a def.)

The problem is that HashMap is not in your scope.  You have imported the module that exports its definition, but that definition lives in the Std namespace.  So either use Std.HashMap in place of HashMap, or add open Std (HashMap) at the beginning of your file, after the import.
The error message you see is confusing because of a feature called "auto implicits", which automatically adds names which appear to be defined nowhere yet are still used in a definition as implicit arguments of that definition.  So the error message is not "HashMap isn't defined anywhere", but rather, "I couldn't determine the type of this variable HashMap which I implicitly added as an argument".  You can turn off that option by adding set_option autoImplicit false, or by adding that option to the whole project in your lakefile.lean or lakefile.toml.

Auto implicit strikes again!  I think anytime there is a type error related to an auto implicit then lean should warn that it could be caused by that type being an auto implicit.

@JasonRute indeed, I opened an RFC about this. I think changing this is overdue.
